# Formally expressing regular expression

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Supposed there is a set of all strings in 0, 1 which is a set of all strings obtained by concatenating a sequence of zeros or more strings.

With this definition, I'd express all strings containing the substring $000$ as $(0 + 1)^*000(0 + 1)^*$ where $+$ represents union.

With this formal expression of regular expression, how can I express a set of strings that contain exactly one occurrence of substring `010` ?

Comment: No not vandalize your post to render it meaningless, aft you accepted the answer.

Comment: Still unclear. Does $01010$ contains one or two occurrences of $010$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin that contains 2 010s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to solve these fiddly problems by working out the right DFA (state machine) and then converting to a regular expression. So first what does a string that doesn’t contain $010$ look like?

Well if you see a 0 then you’re allowed another 0 or 11. If you see a 1 (and aren’t followed by a zero then you’re allowed anything you like. So the regular expression for something not containing $010$ (and not ending in 0) is $\left(1^*(0^*11)^*\right)^*$. Thus an expression for something containing 010 exactly once is:
$$\left(1^*(0^*11)^*\right)^*0^*010\left(\epsilon + 0^*1 + 0^*11\left(1^*(0^*11)^*\right)^*0^*1^*\right)$$
There’s probably a simpler way to express it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't quite get the final answer. Could you please further explain how it works? Thanks again

Comment: The parts correspond to: something without 010 and ending in 1 (or being nothing); then maybe some 0, then 010, then (so we don’t get 01010) you can have the end of the string, or some zeros and a 1 and the end or some zeros and 11, then something that doesn’t contain 010 and ends with a 1 (provided it starts with a 11), then maybe some zeros and some ones and then the end. The easiest way to think about this is to try to construct a string that is/isn’t in the language when it shouldn’t/should be.